# C#: How to fake a drag and drop action of a file to a certain drop-target of a window

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I want to fake a drag and drop action (dragging a file from lets say Windows-Explorer to a certain program). This program has a window with four drop-targets.

The target-program  has its own graphical subsystem, so its neither based on WinForms nor WPF. I tried WinSpy and all it detects is the window itself, but none of the controls.

When I drag above one of the targets it shows a Windows' copy option though (like when you drag a file to a folder on another drive).

Comment: Retrofitting drag+drop for a program that you don't have the source code for is not practical.  Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: There is no way to get any support from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's any documented way.

You could send `WM_DROPFILES`, but this (1) requires you to put the filename into an undocumented HDROP structure in the target process memory ahead of time, and (2) is the older method for accepting files, it won't work if the application uses the newer `IDropTarget` APIs.

`IDropTarget` is actually designed to be more general than just dragging files from explorer: there's a Win32 API, [`DoDragDrop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678486.aspx), which allows an application to act as a drag source so the user can drop its data into other applications.  Unfortunately `DoDragDrop` watches mouse movement directly, so you'd need to simulate mouse movement and button release in order to control where the item dropped.  Even this won't work unless the other window is on top of the z-order, since `DoDragDrop` finds the window under the cursor, and will interfere with any mouse activity the user is doing.  So it should be used as a last resort.

Comment: Can't I send a Windows-Message to the target-window directly?

Comment: I looked it it up, the operations of this program use OLE. Does that mean I can use WM_DROPFILES?

Comment: @Hedge: Likely not -- OLE `IDropTarget` replaces `WM_DROPFILES`.  Open the application in Dependency Walker and see whether it imports `RegisterDragDrop` (used with `IDropTarget`) or `DragAcceptFiles` (used with `WM_DROPFILES`).  You could also use Spy++ and watch for the `WM_DROPFILES` message.

Comment: Spy++ can't find any messages at all (for the window of the app) when I watch for them. I found RegisterDragDrop in Ole32.dll marked with a blue 'C' (whatever that means). So I have no way to fake the drag and drop-operations?